# Simple change in cmd isn't working

Tags: cmd

I'm typing `d:` in cmd and I'm transfered to d:\Documents

How can I type `d:` and enter in D drive?

Comment: type `cd c:\ ` to change to the non default root. NB Only CMD, for compatability reasons with MSDos, has the concept of a default directory for a drive. Windows programs don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as usual. When you change the drive in cmd, it generally takes you to the folder path where you were when you visited last time to the destination drive within the time period of the current session of cmd.

So, you can go to the path and give `cd..` command to go to the parent directory. 
This command would bring you from `D:\Documents` path to `D:\` path.

Or you can simply open a new session of cmd and change the drive. But remember, in case of `C:` drive, where your windows is in, it would take you to a defined folder named after your user name under `Users` folder.

Answer (score 4):

To change the drive and the directory at the same time, use the cd command followed by the /d switch. The parameter is used to change the current drive to a specific folder from other partition. For example, now you are on the 'D:' drive and you want to go back to the 'C:' drive directly to the Windows folder. Type cd/d C:\Windows and press Enter.

By typing the drive letter you automatically move to your most recent location in that drive. For example if you are on 'd:' drive and type cd c:\windows nothing happen. But, if you type 'c:' then the working will change to c:\windows (assuming that it was the last directory you worked with on c: drive